# unable to add azure storage api nuget packages to my console app

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-storage

For my bot, I wanted to save data in to Azure storage table. I'm following the instructions from this [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet) to add Azure storage API to my console application (.net=4.5.2v). When installing below package got an error

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table -Version 1.1.3
```

**Error**

```
Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.22.0' is not compatible with 'Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 1.1.3 constraint: 
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB (>= 1.22.0)
```

I tried installing the dependent library `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` using

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB -Version 1.22.0
```

Then I tried installing `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` which gives the same error

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e55dc5f-6f5c-450a-8837-224c2aaafa82/unable-to-install-cosmosdb-library?forum=azurecosmosdb) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.22.0' is not compatible with 'Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 1.1.3 constraint: 
>   Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB (>= 1.22.0)

I can reproduce same issue. I check the dependencies of [Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 1.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/) and find that it requires ***Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common (>= 8.6.0-preview && <= 9.0.0.1-preview)***.

[image]

To solve the issue, you can downgrade **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common** to **9.0.0.1-preview**. The following `packages.config` works for me, you can try to use it in your console application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.22.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common" version="9.0.0.1-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="7.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to install this by using below command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table -IncludePrerelease
```

Refer this [git issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/issues/385#issuecomment-397853917)